# How to make the text on UILabel appear on the top-left corner after adding constraints?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, uilabel

I'm developing an iOS application that has a `Segue` where some information is displayed. The information that I'm displaying is appearing in the middle of the `Segue` and I want it to appear right below the *X* or close button.

[image: This is how the text is appearing and I want to appear right below the X button]

I added the constraints necessary in the `Storyboard` and in the `Storyboard` I see it as I want it, but it's not translating when the application is ran. The text where I'm having problems can be seen in the picture below in the right, which is the `Segue`.

[image: Auto-layout in Storyboard, I'm having problems with the label on the View Controller that's on the right]

The following code snippet is meant to make the text start from the top left corner of the label text.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    infoLabel.text = text
    infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    infoLabel.sizeToFit()
    
}
```

but after adding some constraints on that label to make it adapt to other screen sizes the text stopped starting on the top-left corner and started right in the middle-left corner. How can I fix this?

Comment: remove the leading constraint.

Comment: Do you mean the text inside the label is not adapting or the label itself?
Are you trying to use a Righ-to-Left language such as Farsi, Arabic,... as text on the label?

Comment: @JaimeMiranda - your image is not showing the full constraint setup... What is the bottom constraint set to? If you ***delete*** that bottom constraint, your label text should show up at the top.

Comment: But if I delete the bottom constraint wouldn’t it mess up the screen size compatibility with other devices? @DonMag

Comment: @JaimeMiranda - no, it has nothing to do with that. A `UILabel` uses its text (and font) to determine its own height. If you add a bottom (or height) constraint, that will set the label's heigh. You just want the label to be at the top of the view (screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make label to constrain to right, don't give the leading constraint. Just the trailing, top constraints are enough for a label. Only give width constraint if you want label to take a fixed space.

In your case, just delete the leading constraint.

You can also play with the text alignment, set the text alignment to right if you want to keep your constraints intact.

Comment: I mistakenly said top-right, I want to appear on the top-left cornet, sorry for the confusion. I added another picture showing how the text appears in the app. @Teja Nandamuri

Comment: for top - left, delete the trailing and keep the leading.

Comment: When I do that the text does stay on left, but it doesn't stay on the top. It stays right in the middle like on the picture that I posted on the question. Any idea why? @Teja Nandamuri

Comment: if you have bottom constraint, delete it too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to align the text and set to right alignment

[image]

[image]